# Comma separated value in the same field being grouped on common data

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a requirement that outlines the needs at the following:

[Grouping a comma separated value on common data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950216/grouping-a-comma-separated-value-on-common-data)

I need to group on comma seaparated values that have common data.  The proposed solution by Andreas in the link above works, but is getting stuck in a loop with the first set of values, so correctly updates grp with 1, but then it doesn't do the current_group = currenct_group+1.

Looks like it doesn't break out of the unprocessed: loop, and therefore does not return to main:loop to update the next group.  can't figure out why unprocessed doesn't get set to null.  My first set of values are only two reference, which seem to get repeated an awful lot in the groups table.

Any thoughts?

Comment: wouldn't it be better to as this as a comment to andreas' question? You actually have the same question it seems?

Comment: Yeah, but for some reason I can't add a comment to Andreas' solution.

Comment: You need a certain amount of reputation to comment. If that's a good thing or not is something you might doubt, but those seem to be the rules. Trying to go around them (the comment you posted as an answer and that was removed, and also this question) isn't really the way to go I'm sorry. Best you can do is try and get your reputation up a bit, so you can actually comment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grouping a comma separated value on common data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950216/grouping-a-comma-separated-value-on-common-data)